# optimize sql scan query to get results from postgres db

Tags: sql, postgresql, talend

I'm working on small sql logic

I've one table Messages contaning message_id, accountid as columns

Data is keep coming in this table with unique message id.

My target is to store these mesaages table data into another database. [From postgres(source) DB to postgres(destination) DB]

For this I have set up a ETL job. Which is helping me to transfer the data.

Here comes the problem, In postgres(source) DB where messages table is located, in that table message_id is not in sorted form. And data looks like this  .....

And my etl job runs after in every half an hour, My motive is whenever etl job runs, takes the data from source db to destinaton db on the basis of message_id. In destination db, I'm having one stored procedure which helps me to get the max(message_id) from messages table and store that value in another table. So in ETL I use that value in query which I use to fire on source db for getting the data greater than message_id I got from destination db.

So its kind a load incremental process.using etl. But the query am using to get data from source db is like this http://prnt.sc/b3u5il

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM MESSAGES ORDER BY message_id) as a WHERE message_id >"+context.vid+"
```

This query scans the all table every time it runs...so itakes so much time to execute. I'm getting my desired results. But is there any way so that I could perform this process in more faster way.

Can anyone help me to optimize this query (don't know whether its possible or not) ? or any other suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to improve performance in your case is to a add a **INDEX** to your **sort** column in this case message_id for better performance.

In this way , your query will perform an **index scan instead of a full table** scan which hampers the performance.

You can create an index by using following statement:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If message_id is not the leading column in the primary key or a secondary index, then create an index:

```
... ON MESSAGES (message_id)
```

And eliminate the inline view:

```
 SELECT m.*
   FROM MESSAGES m
  WHERE m.message_id > ?
  ORDER BY m.message_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a B-Tree Index :
You can adjust the ordering of a B-tree index by including the options ASC, DESC, NULLS FIRST, and/or NULLS LAST when creating the index; for example:

CREATE INDEX test2_info_nulls_low ON test2 (info NULLS FIRST);
CREATE INDEX test3_desc_index ON test3 (id DESC NULLS LAST);